# Problems with labels and size in plot

Tags: r, plot

I have a problem to plot my data. I want to change the ticks of x axes. The script is:

```
png(file="plot_day101112.png")
plot(table(created.day_10_df$created.hour),ylab="tweets",type="p",xlab="Time",axes=FALSE,labels=TRUE)
axis(1,at=seq(0,24,1))
lines(table(created.day_11_df$created.hour),ylab="tweets",type="l",xlab="Time")
lines(table(created.day_12_df$created.hour),ylab="tweets",type="b",xlab="Time")
legend(1,1000,"points for the day 10, lines for the day 11, both for the day 12")
dev.off()
```

This graph will be overplotted and there isn't the ticks of y axes.
How can I correct this graph?

I have another similar problem to plot an histogram graph. I want the labels of x axes with these values: (8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20). I don't understand why with this script:

```
png(file="plot_tweets_hour.png")
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
hist(doc0$created.hours,"hours",format="%d %H",freq=TRUE,axes=FALSE,main="Absolute frequency",xlab="Time")
axis(1,at=seq(8,20,1))
axis(2,at=NULL)
hist(doc0$created.hours,"hours",format="%d %H",freq=FALSE,axes=FALSE,main="Relative frequency",xlab="Time")
axis(1,at=seq(8,20,1))
axis(2,at=NULL)
dev.off()
```

the labels of x axes doesn't appear.
Thanks so  much

Comment: you add the y-axis just like you add the x, with `axis(2, ...)`

Comment: Oks, perfect now it is right. But I have another problems: the lines in the plot are out of the windows. How can I correct it? Thanks so much

Comment: probably the range of one of your `table(created.day_11_df$created.hour)` is larger (or smaller) than the plot window which is created by `plot(table(created.day_10_df$created.hour))`. you can either set the range manually with `xlim`/`ylim` in `plot` or add `xpd=NA` in your `lines` (the second option will not fix the range issue, it will just draw the lines no matter where they go)

Comment: Thanks so much, now the plot is perfect! I have another similar problem with another graph. I want to determinate by myself the ticks of x axes. But It doesn't work! My question is: Can I use the function "axis" for the histogram or not? thank so much

Comment: you can define `at` to be whatever you want so long as they are within the ranges that the plot created. So if you `plot(1:5)` but define `axis(1, at = 6:10)`, then nothing will show up because the `at` is out of the range. You could do `plot(1:5); axis(1, at = 1:5, labels = 6:10)`, however. And you should be getting errors with that `hist` because you have "hours" as the `breaks` argument and that is invalid